# Moving particular sub directory if it has "completed.txt" file in it

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-move

Copy directories if their subdirectories contain "connect.txt"
I want to copy multiple directories from one location to another location only if any of the subdirectories of those contain the connect.txt file in them.

Example:

```
C:\ANIMAL\DOG\CONNECT.TXT
C:\PLANET\EARTH\CONNECT.TXT
C:\SYSTEM\USER\ADMIN.TXT
```

Then I ONLY want to copy ANIMAL & PLANET directories to C:\DESKTOP.

INPUT :

```
C:\ANIMAL\TIGER\CONNECT.TXT
C:\ANIMAL\LION\WILD.TXT
C:\PLANET\EARTH\CONNECT.TXT
C:\SYSTEM\USER\ADMIN.TXT
C:\SYSTEM\USER\DOG.TXT
C:\SYSTEM\USER\CAT.TXT
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\DESKTOP\ANIMAL
C:\DESKTOP\EARTH
```

Comment: Well, this is neither a tutorial site nor a free coding service, so I am afraid you are wrong here. This is a question-and-answer place for programming-specific issues. Please read the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve] to learn how to use this site! Starting point: [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), [`if exist`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [`move`](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)...

Comment: Toni, please don't insult us, changing `Copy` to `Move` in the titles, doesn't really show us that you're willing to learn something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -encodedCommand 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
```

whereas the encoded command for the following stands:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter 'Connect.txt' -Recurse -ErrorAction:Ignore -Exclude 'C:\Desktop\*' | ForEach-Object {$_.Directory} | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Desktop\' -Container -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction:Ignore
```

(But don't trust me, copy the characters above in a base64 to text online converter and see for yourself!)